# .NET Core, circular references on particular entity using XMLParser

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, foreign-keys, xmlserializer

I am using C# .Net Core along with the XMLSerializer, I've checked various other questions but none of the provided answers seem to work for me. I Have a MaintenanceMoment that has multiple time blocks, so a one-to-many relation, I've created it like the following:

My Model code:

`PRMaintenanceMoment.cs`

```
    public class PRMaintenanceMoment
    {
      [XmlIgnore]
      public int ID { get; set; }

      [Required]
      [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]
      public string EarliestExecutionDate { get; set; }

      [Required]
      [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]
      public string LatestExecutionDate { get; set; }

      public List<Timeblock> Timeblock { get; set; } = new List<Timeblock>();
    }
```

`Timeblock.cs`

```
public class Timeblock
{
    [XmlIgnore]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("MaintenanceMomentID")]
    public PRMaintenanceMoment MaintenanceMoment { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:hh:mm:ss}")]
    public DateTime EarliestExecutionTime { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:hh:mm:ss}")]
    public DateTime LatestExecutionTime { get; set; }
}
```

The reference in my Database Context has been made like this:
`ApplicationDbContext.cs`

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options) { }

    public DbSet<Timeblock> Timeblocks { get; set; }

 protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
 {
        modelBuilder.Entity<PRMaintenanceMoment>()
            .HasMany(tb => tb.Timeblock)
            .WithOne(pr => pr.MaintenanceMoment);
 }
}
```

My Controller that servers the MaintenanceMoment is created like so (I've excluded the generic repo & interface as they don't matter for this example):

`PRMaintenanceMoment.cs`

```
    public class PRMaintenanceMomentRepository : GenericRepository<PRMaintenanceMoment>, IPRMaintenanceMomentRepository
{
    public PRMaintenanceMomentRepository(ApplicationDbContext context)
        : base(context) { }

    public override List<PRMaintenanceMoment> Index()
    {
        var context = _context.PRMaintenanceMoments
               .Include(PRMaintenanceMoment => PRMaintenanceMoment.Timeblock)
            .ToList();

        return context;
    }

    public void Update(int id, PRMaintenanceMoment maintenanceMoment)
    {
        PRMaintenanceMoment DBPRMaintenanceMoment = _context.PRMaintenanceMoments.FirstOrDefault(ms => ms.ID.Equals(id));

        _context.Entry<PRMaintenanceMoment>(DBPRMaintenanceMoment).CurrentValues.SetValues(maintenanceMoment);

        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

The eventual Migration that is created shows the following:

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "PRMaintenanceMoments",
            columns: table => new
            {
                ID = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
                    .Annotation("MySql:ValueGenerationStrategy", 
                     MySqlValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn),
                EarliestExecutionDate = table.Column<string>(nullable: false),
                LatestExecutionDate = table.Column<string>(nullable: false)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_PRMaintenanceMoments", x => x.ID);
            });

        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "Timeblocks",
            columns: table => new
            {
                ID = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
                    .Annotation("MySql:ValueGenerationStrategy", MySqlValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn),
                MaintenanceMomentID = table.Column<int>(nullable: true),
                EarliestExecutionTime = table.Column<DateTime>(nullable: false),
                LatestExecutionTime = table.Column<DateTime>(nullable: false)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_Timeblocks", x => x.ID);
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_Timeblocks_PRMaintenanceMoments_MaintenanceMomentID",
                    column: x => x.MaintenanceMomentID,
                    principalTable: "PRMaintenanceMoments",
                    principalColumn: "ID",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
            });

        migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
            name: "IX_PlanningRequests_PRMaintenanceMomentID",
            table: "PlanningRequests",
            column: "PRMaintenanceMomentID");

        migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
            name: "IX_Timeblocks_MaintenanceMomentID",
            table: "Timeblocks",
            column: "MaintenanceMomentID");
```

Which seems quite alright to me, then, as many questions suggest is adding the `ReferenceLoopHandling` from the JSON serializer. I've tried this but this didn't seem to help. For completion's sake, I've added the most important bits of my startup.cs file; this is of course not the full file, but the most important settings.

`startup.cs`

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllers()
             .AddXmlSerializerFormatters(); // Adding the XML serializer here

        services.AddMvc(options =>
        {
            options.MaxValidationDepth = 64;
            options.InputFormatters.Add(new XmlSerializerInputFormatter(options));
            options.OutputFormatters.Add(new XmlDataContractSerializerOutputFormatter());
        });

services.AddMvc().AddNewtonsoftJson(jsonOptions => { jsonOptions.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;  });

Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
}

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
```

Finally the exact error thrown is:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error generating the XML document.
---> System.InvalidOperationException: A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type SALES005.Models.PRMaintenanceMoment.
at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationWriter.WriteStartElement(String name, String ns, Object o, Boolean writePrefixed, XmlSerializerNamespaces xmlns)
at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriterList1.Write3_PRMaintenanceMoment(String n, String ns, PRMaintenanceMoment o, Boolean isNullable, Boolean needType)
at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriterList1.Write2_Timeblock(String n, String ns, Timeblock o, Boolean isNullable, Boolean needType)
at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriterList1.Write3_PRMaintenanceMoment(String n, String ns, PRMaintenanceMoment o, Boolean isNullable, Boolean needType)
at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriterList1.Write4_ArrayOfPRMaintenanceMoment(Object o)
```

Comment: You should only build the tables one.  Running you code more than once is creating duplicate tables in the database and causing the error.  You would need to delete the table(s) from the database before you run the CreateTable methods a second time.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow; both tables are only created once. The index is indeed added later in the migration but that shouldn't cause any issues I believe?

Comment: How many times did you run the code to create the tables?

Comment: I ran the code once; Using the migrations tool

Comment: It is not obvious from posted code what is causing the error "A circular reference was detected"

Comment: That's the exact issue that I have been having indeed, calling a get request to the Index causes this error. Should I add more code to make the specific issue more clear? If so what would be needed?

Comment: XML serialize is very hard to debug.  Usually I comment out sections of the c# classes to isolate where the issue is occurring.  The serialize will ignore XML tags not in the c# classes.  So you can comment out properties in the classes until the error goes ways.

Comment: Removing the XML parser entirely does make it that the relationship works without any issue, however I still need the output / input the be XML, so whilst it proves that the code is functional, it unfortunately does not solve the problem

Comment: You have to isolate exactly which class property is causing issue.  I usually comment all the class properties and then slowly uncomment until I find the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Newtonsoft` can solve the json circular reference, but it can not solve the xml. So you can change the query method.

```
public List<PRMaintenanceMoment> get6()
    {
        var pRMaintenanceMoments = (from prm in _db.PRMaintenanceMoment
                     
                   select new PRMaintenanceMoment
                   {
                       ID=prm.ID,
                        EarliestExecutionDate=prm.EarliestExecutionDate,
                         LatestExecutionDate=prm.LatestExecutionDate,
                         Timeblock=prm.Timeblock.Select(c=>new Timeblock
                         {
                              ID=c.ID,
                         }).ToList()
                          
                   }).ToList();
        return pRMaintenanceMoments;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: This indeed does seem to work when implemented, could you explain why this specific solution does work whilst my current context does not? Or provide some documentation link so I could work these out by myself in the future?

Comment: `Include` :  EF Core passes a representation of the LINQ query to the database provider. Database providers in turn translate it to database-specific query language. May generate multiple layers of queries. [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/). In some cases, it cannot solve some problems. In this case, you need to use complex queries to make the converted SQL statements more detailed. [Complex Query Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/complex-query-operators)

Comment: Thanks for the additional explanation, I'll have a look through the complex query operators with the link you provided.